# Using simple_form to set data-content

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I'm using Simple_form with Rails 3.2.1

All fine, except that I need to set the 'data-content' attribute for the input_html for bootstrap popover

However, when I use the following Rails/Ruby doesn't like the code as there is a dash in the 'data-content' method:

```
<%= f.input :first_name, :required => true, :label => "First Name", :autofocus => true, :input_html => {:rel => "tooltip", :title => "Testing!", :data-content => "Popover content"}
```

and i get an error:

```
 undefined local variable or method `content'
```

Does anyone know how you can set data-content for input elements using simple_form???

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `-` in ruby symbols but you can use a string like `"data-content"`. So, this will probably work:

```
<%= f.input :first_name, :required => true, :label => "First Name", :autofocus => true, :input_html => {:rel => "tooltip", :title => "Testing!", 'data-content'=> "Popover content"}
```

Comment: You can use hyphens in symbol names, e.g. :"yes-you-can"

Comment: @s In fact this is not a symbol, this is a string converted to a symbol. The same as `"my-string".to_sym`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the data setting as follows:

```
<%= f.input blar..., :input_html => { :data => { content: => "Popover content"}}
```

this should give you an attribute `data-content="Popover content"`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use hyphens in your symbol names. `:data-content` is interpreted as `:data - content` => the symbol `:data` minus `content.

Instead, wrap it in quotes `... "data-content" => "Popover content" ...`